# MacBook Pro 15" 2011 - missing audio device (no sound driver)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, driver, sound-volume

I have a problem with a 15" MacBook Pro (2011, OSX 10.7.5): After being repaired due to a water damage recently, the sound was just working fine. Some days later the audio device in the status bar turned gray and the MacBook didn't play any audio anymore.

After having tried several approaches to solve the problem (e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1736638?start=345&tstart=0)

So I repaired HDD permissions and deleted `~Library/Preferences/com.apple.BezelServices.plist` in normal and safe-mode of OSX. After a restart the speaker icon is highlighted again and sound was available again.

But another restart later it didn't work again. Now the approach mentioned before also didn't solve it anymore. As the soundcard was working fine temporarly I'm guessing it's just a software issue.

How can I come closer to a solution?

Comment: Is this problem specific for your user account or does this happen on other user accounts as well? You can make a new account and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Did not check that. Since reseting the PRAM helped, do you still think it can be account specific?

Comment: No clue. Making a new user account and testing if the audio problem persist will not take much time, so you can try it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this before (grey icon, no sound) by resetting the PRAM.

1. Turn off your Mac
2. Turn on your Mac
3. Hold Down Cmd-Opt-P-R
4. Keep Holding until you have heard the startup sound **twice**

[Apple Support Document HT1379](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)

Comment: solved it! thanks a lot! Curious why/how this is interconnected with the "BezelServices.plist", which also solved it temporarly.

Comment: Another restart later, the friend I checked the MacBook for told me, that it's the same problem again.

Comment: Hmm. I'm out of ideas then I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If resetting the PRAM doesn't work, you may try installing the latest Combo Update, like this one:

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 Update - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1833?locale=en_US