# Any fixes for persistent NO SOUND issue on 16" MBP (2020) OS 11.2…?

Tags: mac, speakers

Speakers not recognized by computer. Numerous calls with Apple Support ("AS" herein) team members… Tried all manner of solutions.  After 3 months, 7 store Genius Bar visits, computer was replaced.

Worked great for 9 days, then…pffft!  No Sound.

Another 90 min phone session with AS yesterday…  Erased HD

Re-installed Big Sur…  Still no joy.

Tried several of the suggested solutions in the "Restarting Sound Service?" thread
( [Restarting sound service?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16842/restarting-sound-service/121342#121342) )

No go.

Last note:  I'm a musician.  Default DAW: Logic Pro

All software duly purchased or licensed...

3rd pty software: Native instruments Komplete 8 (use only some of it),

Sibelius

I suspect possible culprit(s) Native Instruments… ??

Any ideas where to look?

Thank you. Max

[image: screenshot: sound output]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81812/macbook-pro-15-2011-missing-audio-device-no-sound-driver

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies if these seem redundant after all the support calls you’ve done...)

1. After erase & reinstalling, did you check speakers *before* installing your audio apps?
2. Does Safe Mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot) help?
3. What is the output of `ioreg -r -c AppleHDAEngineInput ; ioreg -r -c AppleHDAEngineOutput`?
4. What audio devices have you been attaching to your system? (Wondering if something might be overdriving the input preamp past an absolute maximum rating...)

**UPDATE:**

> Yes I did check speakers before migrating. They worked.

This is a **very important** piece of data - it rules out hardware as being at fault. So now we’re solely focusing on what pieces of software in your migration caused this regression.

We can do this a few ways:

1. Create a new user account, reboot, log in with the new account first, and check your audio. This won’t help unless the cause is a user-specific misconfiguration.
2. You can try uninstalling one audio app at a time. This won’t help if the uninstaller of the offending software doesn’t do a thorough cleanup.
3. Reformat and reinstall the OS but do *not* migrate. Instead, install your audio software, one app at a time, until you see the failure. This is the most reliable (and most time-consuming) path towards root cause.

The `ioreg` command requires Xcode to be installed. If you don’t want to install it (understandably so), you can download [IOJones](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iojones/) and use its filter bar to search for `AppleHDAEngineInput` and `AppleHDAEngineOutput`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks Pion for your reply. Answers: 
1, Yes I did check speakers before migrating. They worked.  
2, Safe Mode during start up didn't change a thing.  Neither did all the other "round up the usual suspects" bag of work-arounds/fixes.  
3, "zsh: command not found: $”   
4. No audio devices attached.  (Two external USB C drives —one for my Logic folders, one for  iTunes and Native Instruments. ) 
Thanks again.

Comment: 1.  The "New User Account" play was run several times. No joy: no speakers "found".         2. I've been zeroing in on Native Instr. as those are the only 3rd pty audio apps I have. This morning i uninstalled / deleted most of them (along with their corresponding bits in Lib>App Support and/or Audio)…  No joy.    3. Planning to reformat, re-install and NOT migrate either tomorrow or Sunday.  Will comment.  Again, my heartfelt thanks for your time.

Comment: Grab a couple of screenshots from *IOJones* with the above filters before you reformat so we can compare before & after.

Comment: @MaxV52 Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the radio silence, was thoroughly burnt out.  My computer was replaced.  Result: the problem was put to rest.  Side note: I did a clean install ( "as new,") and selectively migrated only some files . As a precaution, I have yet to re-install Native Instruments… and when I do, I will download all the sound files again (but not before doing a full backup). In the meantime, it's great to have a working computer again.  Thanks for all the help.  —Max

Comment: @MaxV52 Glad it worked out, one way or another. If you found this answer helpful, would you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: Happy to, @pion.  How do I do that?

Comment: @MaxV52 Just click on the checkmark underneath the vote up/down arrows at the top left of my answer. Thanks!